# Show that the collection of sets that are unions of finite numbers of elements of a countable decomposition is an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

In the book "Probability" by A. N. Shiryaev, Page 140, he writes the following:

> Let $\mathcal{D}:=\{D_{1},D_{2},\dots\}$ be a countable decomposition of $\Omega$ into nonempty sets $\Omega=D_{1}\cup D_{2}\cup\dots$ with $D_{i}\cap D_{j}=\varnothing$ for $i\neq j$. Then, the system $\mathcal{A}$ formed by the sets that are unions of finite numbers of elements of the decomposition, is an algebra.

My question is, how can this $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra? And what can I refine for $\mathcal{A}$ to make it an algebra?

---

To begin with, I do not think that $\Omega$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$. But this is easy to solve, we can let $\mathcal{A}$ contain $\Omega$.

Clearly, $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite unions. We do not need to worry about this.

But, I do not think that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complement. Say, $A\in\mathcal{A}$ is written as $A=D_{1}\cup D_{2}$, then isn't $A^{c}$  a countable union $D_{3}\cup D_{4}\cup\dots$? Am I missing anything here?

Thank you!

Comment: I am confused by the use of the word "algebra". Does he mean $\sigma$-algebra, as you assume, or is he using the usual definition of an algebra, i.e. a vector space with a bilinear product? In the former case, we have all the problems you mention, and in the latter case, I don't see how scalar multiplication would work...

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim An algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ such that $\Omega\in\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite unions and complements. I am not sure if this is aligned with the vector space definition you mentioned.

Comment: Okay, then he is using a non-standard definition for the word "algebra". In this case, you are completely correct: if $\mathcal{D}$ is not finite, which is see no reason for it to be, then you are not closed under complements.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Thanks! Any suggestion for me to add anything to $\mathcal{A}$ to make it an algebra?

Comment: You will have to add all the complements, i.e. $\mathcal{A}$ should be all the finite unions along with the complement of all finite unions. In this way, you also get $\Omega\in \mathcal{A}$, being the complement of the *empty* union.
The complements are exactly the "anti-finite" unions, i.e. the union of all but finitely many elements of $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is a typo. It turned out that the book I was reading was the second edition. Recently, I've found the third edition in the library, and now it is called Probability-1, since the edition broke the original book to two sub-books due to the increasing number of contents, especially exercises and some applied theories. (I always thought that Probability - 1 was the older edition, perhaps due to its publication or coloring style.)

In the third edition, the statement has been altered to:

> The system $\mathcal{A}$, form be the sets that are **finite or countable unions** of elements of the decomposition (**including the empty set**) is an algebra (**and a $\sigma$-algebra**).

Yes, so my suspicion was correct. The system defined in the second edition was not an algebra, but if you add countable unions into it, it makes $\mathcal{A}$ into a $\sigma$-algebra. A mid-ground is what suggested in the comment, we add all the complements.